# printf printing more lines in the for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, vector, printf

I am having problem with an encryption algorithm in C, I'm encoding an AES criptography, I'm debugging one function, and this function is printing more lines than the for loop count. Below the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned char key[]   = {
                              0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
                              0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
                             };

                              unsigned char state[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff};

    const unsigned char sbox[256] =
    {
//0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F
        0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76, //0
        0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0, //1
        0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15, //2
        0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75, //3
        0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84, //4
        0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf, //5
        0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8, //6
        0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2, //7
        0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73, //8
        0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb, //9
        0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79, //A
        0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, //B
        0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, //C
        0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e, //D
        0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf, //E
        0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
    }; //F

    const unsigned char Rcon[10] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36};


    unsigned char buf1, buf2, buf3, buf4, round, i;
    unsigned char rcon;


      for (round = 0; round < 10; round++){
    //add key + sbox
    for (i = 0; i <16; i++){
      state[i]=sbox[state[i] ^ key[i]];
    }
    for (i = 0; i<16; i++){
      printf("\n%d",state[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The print function (as shown above):

```
   for (round = 0; round < 10; round++){
        //add key + sbox
        for (i = 0; i <16; i++){
          state[i]=sbox[state[i] ^ key[i]];
        }
        for (i = 0; i<16; i++){
          printf("\n%d",state[i]);
        }
      }
```

The output:

```
99
202
183
4
9
83
208
81
205
96
224
231
186
112
225
140
251
31
213
197
215
177
246
177
166
249
135
206
78
255
223
236
15
114
14
180
102
141
140
78
228
140
93
166
44
137
62
17
118
143
254
169
170
196
126
59
206
151
91
149
183
95
4
114
56
25
176
172
228
120
188
235
180
11
209
11
234
0
103
255
7
173
55
121
225
255
244
206
101
119
185
99
142
215
249
140
197
145
150
218
217
45
137
221
60
243
109
69
19
87
104
236
166
96
34
53
193
52
115
87
24
45
133
47
192
190
51
17
36
239
183
5
166
199
157
83
202
54
115
54
75
109
39
114
54
40
213
111
58
37
20
32
37
117
182
39
160
208
165
255
```

Someone knows what is happening?

Comment: 160 numbers and `for (round = 0; round < 10; round++){ ...
        for (i = 0; i<16; i++){
          printf("\n%d",state[i]);` --> Why is that wrong with 10*16 = 160?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your print with the loop counters to help debugging:-

```
for (i = 0; i<16; i++){
  printf("\n[%d %d] %d",round, i, state[i]);
}
```

Output:-

```
[0 0] 99
[0 1] 202
....
....
[9 14] 165
[9 15] 255
```

10 X 16 = 160 lines

Answer (score 2):

You have two nested loops one with 10 and another with 16 iterations,so you got 160 lines printed

Answer (score 1):

The inner for loop for (i = 0; i<16; i++)... prints 16 numbers, one on each line. This inner for loop is called by the outer one 10 times. 16 lines, 10 times, is 160 numbers.